# Exceptions Using Microsoft.Speech SpeechSynthesizer

Tags: c#, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

I'm working on a speech synthesis project, and I decided to try and use the Microsoft.Speech namespace instead of the built-in System.Speech namespace because Microsoft isn't fixing the memory leak [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/664196/system-speech-has-a-memory-leak) and recommends using Microsoft.Speech as a workaround.

When I run the program below, I get a `NullReferenceException` when it calls `GetInstalledVoices`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Speech.Synthesis;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
            synth.GetInstalledVoices();
        }
    }
}
```

And when I run this next program, I get a `UnauthorizedAccessException` (I am running as an administrator) when it calls `Speak`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Speech.Synthesis;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
            synth.Speak("exception");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm running VS Express 2012 on Windows 8 x64, and the project is configured for x64.  I installed the x64 runtime and SDK for Microsoft speech, and installed the en-us language pack from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27224.  I even tried downloading the x86 runtime and SDK and changing my project to x86, but that results in a `PlatformNotSupportedException`.

Is there some other install I'm missing, or is the Microsoft.Speech namespace just not supported on my platform?  If I change `using Microsoft.Speech.Synthesis` to `using System.Speech.Synthesis`, it's fine except for the memory leak that I mentioned, and I can probably get away with that for now, since this is a hobby application, not for work.

Comment: did you try to build the app in x86?

Comment: @FelicePollano, yeah, but it gives me a `PlatformNotSupportedException`, even though I was pointing to the x86 SDK assembly at the time.

Comment: I think I see the leak, there's one line of code missing in the ConvertTextFrag.FreeTextSegment() method.  Adding fragment.Free() ought to fix the leak.  Kinda sad this can't get fixed, nobody seems to care enough about this to get this resolved through Microsoft Support.  Too many hobby projects maybe.  The feedback article already mentions trouble with voices, sounds like you are seeing this too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using [eSpeak](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/) instead, and just shelling out to their command line program from my .Net program.  This is a better solution for me because eSpeak and it's associated voice are easy to install on multiple computers - if I used the Microsoft Speech solutions, I would be stuck with whatever the default voices on that computer are, unless we bought voices for each computer.  It also happens that the robotic-sounding eSpeak voice is a better fit for my project, because guess what, it's a talking robot head!

Comment: @RobertHarvey, yes, and answered by the asker, no less.  Honestly, as someone just getting started playing around with speech, it doesn't seem like Microsoft cares too much about making this work very well, so "use something else" becomes a viable answer.

Answer (score 1):

It takes me some time but i realized that i installed only **MSSpeech_SR_en-US_TELE.msi** which means SpeechRecognition. You need to scroll down in installer and install also text to speech e.g. "MSSpeech_TTS_en-US_Helen.msi".

Comment: For what it's worth, I did this and still had the same problem. However, I then realized that I had V11 of the platform installed, but had installed V10 of the voice packs. After uninstalling the V10 voices and reinstalling the V11 versions, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and noticed that it was a first-time-run problem. So what I did to solve this, is I have a `List<InstalledVoice> InstalledVoices;` declared as a global property.

Then in the Form.Load(), I have this:

```
while (InstalledVoices == null)
{
    InstalledVoices = SpeechSynth.GetInstalledVoices().ToList();
}
```

When I ran the debug output on that, it failed once, then succeeded the second time.

That guarantees that you have a collection of the Installed Voices and no null reference. SpeechSynth is my instance of the `SpeechSynthesizer` class. I store each `InstalledVoice` in a `Dictionary<string, VoiceInfo>` for later reference.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you that Windows updates have been installed.

I tried to get away with a Windows 7 installation without any updates, and something like SpeechSynthesizer.SelectVoice(SomeVoiceName) would fail.

The only solution was to get the automatic Windows updates. Not sure which update exactely resolved the issue.

But I stumble over this problem again and again when I test my app in a VM with Windows 7 without updates.